# How to load tfjs model into python using keras/tensorflow

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I have a pre trained tfjs model and I would like to load it into python using keras / tensorflow

I found how to convert a tf and a [keras model to tfjs models.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter) And how to [load tfjs model using js](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/webcam-transfer-learning.html),

How can I load the model into python?

Answer (score 3):

You can save the tfjs model from JS using the [model save API](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.5/#tf.Model.save).

You can then convert the model into a python compatible format using the [tfjs-converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter).   Finally, you should be able to use load_model in python using the keras load model API.

```
tf.keras.models.load_model(
   filepath,
   custom_objects=None,
   compile=True
)
```

Comment: I do not need to load keras model in tf, I need to load a tfjs model in keras

Comment: You can save the tfjs model from JS using the model save API.  You can then convert the model into a python compatible format using the converter.  Then you should be able to use  load_model in python.

Comment: This was the question, please edit the answer to that so I can accept it

Comment: Updated.  Thanks.  hope it helped